# Search cell(s) if it contains any of the strings in array and remove them

Tags: excel, vba

I looked for a VBA solution but I got non-VBA solutions and nested Excel formula solutions. That would be too many nested formulas.

I'm comparing a large string of text like **FC123ABC2XLBLK**.
If it contains any of the strings within the array, such as **2XL** , remove the **2XL** resulting in **FC123ABCBLK**.

This is what I have so far.

```vb
Function REMOVESIZE(strInput As String, rngFind As Range) As String

Dim sizeArray() As String
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strFind As String

sizeArray = Split("XS,S,M,L,XL,2XL,3XL,4XL,5XL,6XL,7XL", ",")
strTemp = strInput

For Each cell In rngFind

    If InStr(LCase(strTemp), LCase(sizeArray())) <> 0 Then
        'cell contains size
        strFind = cell.Value
        strTemp = Replace(strTemp, sizeArray(), "")
        
    ElseIf InStr(LCase(strTemp), LCase(sizeArray())) = 0 Then
        'cell DOES NOT contain
        MsgBox "DID NOT WORK! THIS IS JUST FILLER"
    End If
    
Next cell
    
REMOVESIZE = strTemp
    
End Function
```

Tried stitching together code and ideas that other people suggested but can't understand how VBA compares strings in arrays.

Comment: Seems like this should be a subroutine instead of a function if you're looping over multiple cells.

Comment: You will need to loop over the array `sizeArray` for each input cell.  Also you need to make sure that your array elements are sorted according to length (longest first) or you will (eg) remove the "L" in "XL" *before* you try to remove the "XL", and just be left with "X"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a UDF which can be called from a worksheet or from another VBA method:

```vb
Function RemoveSize(strInput As String) As String
    Dim sizeArray() As String, strTemp As String, e
    'make sure items are sorted by length...
    sizeArray = Split("2XL,3XL,4XL,5XL,6XL,7XL,XS,XL,S,M,L", ",")
    strTemp = strInput
    For Each e In sizeArray
        If InStr(strTemp, e) > 0 Then
            RemoveSize = Replace(strTemp, e, "")
            Exit Function 'only 1 replacement required?
        End If
    Next e
    RemoveSize = strTemp
End Function
```